# How to get foreign key from eloquent collection in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have hasMany relationship in my User model;

```
 /**
 * Get the posts for the users.
 */
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Posts::class); //foreign key assigned by user_id
}
```

I need to get a foreign id in Eloquent data

Controller;

```
use App\Models\User;

$posts = User::find(1)->posts;

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    //
}
//for example
$foreign_key = $posts->foreign_key;
echo "all posts collection assigned foreign key is; ".$foreign_key;
```

Expected output;

> 1

How can I get the foreign key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following. Since posts has `hasmany` relation so it return collection of object even though you have one item in posts.

```
foreach ($posts as $post) {
     
    echo $post->user_id;
}
```

or

```
 dd($posts->first()->user_id);
```

If you still need one item from posts relationship then you can add one  relationship

```
public function post()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Posts::class); //foreign key assigned by user_id
}
```

then you can access

```
$posts = User::find(1)->post;

$foreign_key =$posts->user_id;
```

Comment: I'm not using for each, your second suggestion `dd($posts->first()->user_id);` is good but I got "Trying to get property 'user_id' of non-object " error. sometimes table doesn't have any record.

Comment: try adding condition    if($post=$posts->first()){
        dd($post->user_id);
        )

Comment: yes you can only do if its hasone relationship or lese you cant do directly.